# Stacked collapsible navbar in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a collapsible `navbar`. Everything works, but the `nav` items aren't stacked under each other like it should be. They are horizontally next to each other.

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded" role="navigation">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsing-navbar">
        &#9776;
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="collapsing-navbar">   
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo</a>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/messages" class="nav-link">Messages</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/logout" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Screenshot:

[image: bootstrap4 error]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 (since alpha 6 version stacked menu is built in - no need to use extra CSS):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/EZjpmB)

Comment: Thank you. Will this later be supported, or there is no chance?

Comment: Any idea what css you would add to make this work if there was a second navbar in your code that was pulled right like so with nav items in it? If you had a left and right section of your menu.

<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right"></ul>

When you expand the collapsed navbar any nav items within that bar will still be pulled right.

Comment: I would add class to the left navbar (for example my-navbar-left) and add this to CSS so it would apply only to this navbar. Example: `.my-navbar-left .navbar-nav .nav-item { float: none; }`.

Comment: Here is an example of what I meant, the right nav items are still pulled right when expanding on a smaller screen size.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOyMWz

 Should this be set up differently or use css to adjust them?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpBJWV - Changes: instead of using `pull-right` I created new class (`.navbar-right`) and applied to that class style (`float: right`) on screens wider than `34em`). The problem with `.pull-right` class is that it has `!important` rule. I think this is the best solution for now. I think people should not use Bootstrap 4 for development yet (for learing - why not). If you create site based on Bootstrap 4 you may have problems when final version will come out.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>It seems that it's easier done with this CSS override:</strike>

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav>.nav-item {
        float: none;
        margin-left: .1rem;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        float:none !important;
    }
    .navbar .collapse.in, .navbar .collapsing  {
        clear:both;
    }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/Ar1H2G4JVH

### **UPDATE**

As of BS4 alpha 6, the **extra CSS is no longer needed**. The navbar markup has changed.
http://www.codeply.com/go/0OMz6nfPLr

Answer (score 3):

As of **Bootstrap 4 Alpha 5** you can leverage a `collapse` plugin:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="navbarResponsive">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="responsiveNavbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="responsiveNavbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline float-lg-right">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```